# How to only extract the full words of a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I want to extract only the full words of a string.

I have this df:

```
                     Students  Age
0           Boston Terry Emma   23
1      Tommy Julien Cambridge   20
2                      London   21
3                New York Liu   30
4  Anna-Madrid+       Pauline   26
5         Mozart    Cambridge   27
6             Gigi Tokyo Lily   18
7      Paris Diane Marie Dive   22
```

And I want to extract the FULL words from the string, NOT parts of it (ex: I want Liu if Liu is written in names, not iu if just iu if written, because Liu is not iu.)

```
cities = ['Boston', 'Cambridge', 'Bruxelles', 'New York', 'London', 'Amsterdam', 'Madrid', 'Tokyo', 'Paris']
liked_names = ['Emma', 'Pauline', 'Tommy Julien', 'iu']
```

Desired df:

```
                     Students  Age     Cities   Liked Names
0           Boston Terry Emma   23     Boston          Emma
1      Tommy Julien Cambridge   20  Cambridge  Tommy Julien
2                      London   21     London           NaN
3                New York Liu   30   New York           NaN
4  Anna-Madrid+       Pauline   26     Madrid       Pauline
5         Mozart    Cambridge   27  Cambridge           NaN
6             Gigi Tokyo Lily   18      Tokyo           NaN
7      Paris Diane Marie Dive   22      Paris           NaN
```

I tried this code:

```
pat = f'({"|".join(cities)})'
df['Cities'] = df['Students'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
pat = f'({"|".join(liked_names)})'
df['Liked Names'] = df['Students'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
```

My code for cities works, I just need to repair the issue for the 'Liked Names'.

How to make this work? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Yes, I am trying to not match 'Liu' when 'iu' appears in the liked_names

Comment: And if I run my code, then 'iu' would appear on the line where Liu appears.. :(

Comment: Try `df['Cities'] = df['Students'].str.extract( r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(sorted(cities, key=len, reverse=True))) )` and `df['Liked Names'] = df['Students'].str.extract( r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(sorted(liked_names, key=len, reverse=True))) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are word boundaries. In a regular expression they can be expressed with a `\b`. An ugly (albeit working) solution is to modify the `liked_names` list to include word boundaries and then run the code:

```
l = [
    ["Boston Terry Emma", 23],
    ["Tommy Julien Cambridge", 20],
    ["London", 21],
    ["New York Liu", 30],
    ["Anna-Madrid+       Pauline", 26],
    ["Mozart    Cambridge", 27],
    ["Gigi Tokyo Lily", 18],
    ["Paris Diane Marie Dive", 22],
]

cities = [
    "Boston",
    "Cambridge",
    "Bruxelles",
    "New York",
    "London",
    "Amsterdam",
    "Madrid",
    "Tokyo",
    "Paris",
]
liked_names = ["Emma", "Pauline", "Tommy Julien", "iu"]
# here we modify the liked_names to include word boundaries.
liked_names = [r"\b" + n + r"\b" for n in liked_names]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["Students", "Age"])

pat = f'({"|".join(cities)})'
df["Cities"] = df["Students"].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
pat = f'({"|".join(liked_names)})'
df["Liked Names"] = df["Students"].str.extract(pat, expand=False)

print(df)
```

A nicer solution would be to include the word boundaries in the creation of the regular expression.

I first tried using `\s`, i.e. whitespace, but that did not work at the end of the list, so `\b` was the solution. You can check https://regular-expressions.mobi/wordboundaries.html?wlr=1 for some details.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked great on ALL test cases!! <3

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
liked_names = ["Emma", "Pauline", "Tommy Julien", "iu"]

pat = (
    "(" + "|".join(r"[a-zA-Z]*{}[a-zA-Z]*".format(n) for n in liked_names) + ")"
)

df["Liked Names"] = df["Students"].str.extract(pat)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                     Students  Age   Liked Names
0           Boston Terry Emma   23          Emma
1      Tommy Julien Cambridge   20  Tommy Julien
2                      London   21           NaN
3                New York Liu   30           Liu
4  Anna-Madrid+       Pauline   26       Pauline
5         Mozart    Cambridge   27           NaN
6             Gigi Tokyo Lily   18           NaN
7      Paris Diane Marie Dive   22           NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrej Kesely! It would still be an issue. For example for the liked_names = ["Emma", "Pauline", "ommy"], it would put Tommy in the column, instead of NaN. How this could be repaired?

Comment: @ElisaL. This couldn't been repaired easily. You need some logic how to distinguish wanted and not-wanted names.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an additional check to see if matched name is in `Students` column.

```py
import numpy as np

def check(row):
    if row['Liked Names'] == row['Liked Names']:
        # If `Liked Names` is not nan

        # Get all possible names
        patterns = row['Students'].split(' ')

        # If matched `Liked Names` in `Students`
        isAllMatched = all([name in patterns for name in row['Liked Names'].split(' ')])

        if not isAllMatched:
            return np.nan
        else:
            return row['Liked Names']
    else:
        # If `Liked Names` is nan, still return nan
        return np.nan

df['Liked Names'] = df.apply(check, axis=1)
```

```
# print(df)

                     Students  Age     Cities   Liked Names
0           Boston Terry Emma   23     Boston          Emma
1      Tommy Julien Cambridge   20  Cambridge  Tommy Julien
2                      London   21     London           NaN
3                New York Liu   30   New York           NaN
4  Anna-Madrid+       Pauline   26     Madrid       Pauline
5         Mozart    Cambridge   27  Cambridge           NaN
6             Gigi Tokyo Lily   18      Tokyo           NaN
7      Paris Diane Marie Dive   22      Paris           NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is still an issue for liked_names = ['Emma', 'Pauline', 'ommy', 'Julien', 'iu'] this array, as it does not write Julien in the Liked Names columns in the Tommy Julien Cambridge row :( How this could be repaired?

Comment: @ElisaL. If `iu` doesn't match `Liu`, then `ommy` shouldn't match `Tommy`.

Comment: yes exactly! but it should match Julien from Tommy Julien Cambridge :(

Comment: @ElisaL. I understand what you are saying now, the `pat` for your new `liked_name` is `(Emma|Pauline|ommy|Julien|iu)`. When it matches `Tommy Julien Cambridge`, it seems `str.extract()` only returns the `ommy` matched. Actually, we want all possible matched to be returned.